# Build a dynamic HTML elements

Tags: jquery

I want build a dynamic HTML elements. All works well, no errors, but the result when I display the content:

```
<div class="search-result">
 [object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]
 <span class="ionicon ion-ios-close-outline"></span>
</div>
```

My code:

```js
$('form.search-form a.btn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($('div.search-result')) {
    $('div.search-result').remove();
  };
  var $searchResult = $("<div/>", {
    "class": "search-result"
  });
  var $searchClose = $("<span/>", {
    "class": "ionicon ion-ios-close-outline"
  });

  var $html = '';
  $term = $.trim($('#myInput').val());
  $filter = $term.toUpperCase();
  $('span.aliment-title').each(function(index) {
    $txtValue = $(this).text();
    if ($txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf($filter) > -1) {
      $html += $(this).clone();
    }
  });
  $searchResult.html($html);
  $('header.site-header').append($searchResult);
  $searchResult.append($searchClose);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$html +=  $(this).clone();` returns an object, so `$html +=  $(this).clone();` adds the String representation of the object to your html variable, which is always "[object Object]", what you probably want is `$html +=  $(this).clone()[0].outerHTML;` or simply `$html += this.outerHTML;` which accesses the html element.

So in full your code would look like this:

```js
$('form.search-form a.btn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($('div.search-result')) {
    $('div.search-result').remove();
  };
  var $searchResult = $("<div/>", {
    "class": "search-result"
  });
  var $searchClose = $("<span/>", {
    "class": "ionicon ion-ios-close-outline"
  });

  var $html = '';
  $term = $.trim($('#myInput').val());
  $filter = $term.toUpperCase();
  $('span.aliment-title').each(function(index) {
    $txtValue = $(this).text();
    if ($txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf($filter) > -1) {
      $html += this.outerHTML;
    }
  });
  $searchResult.html($html);
  $('header.site-header').append($searchResult);
  $searchResult.append($searchClose);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$searchResult` is object, you can get div content by `$searchResult.outerHTML()`

Change your line of code to

```
$('header.site-header').append($searchResult.outerHTML());
```

Comment: `.outerHTML()` is not a standard jquery function: https://jquery.com/?s=outerHTML  and if it was a DOM object then it would be `.outerHTML`